# libgdx - Touch and drag not working (lagging behind and shown at 2 places)

Tags: android, libgdx, touch

So I edited this post and updated with the current code.
When I set unproject to false in LetterActor i can drag the letters but not correctly, they lag behind my finger and dont end up where i release the touch. 
Also the letter/actor gets drawn in two places when I touch it. It flickers between both positions.

When I set unproject to true, nothing is shown on the screen at all.

What am I missing?

If i undertand correctly unproject takes you from screen coirdinates to game coordinates where game coordinates is your internal representation of the game. But then you would have to define how the game coordinates and screen coordinates relate to each other or how would unproject know what to do? How is this done?
And when you draw to screen again, shouldnt you project again then?

I see it as:
1. Unproject to get internal game coordinates of the event
2. Update internal game representation with the new event
3. Project to get screen coordinates again

```
package com.xxxx.yyyy;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Camera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;

public class LetterActor extends Actor
{
    private Texture texture;
    private Vector3 touchPosition = new Vector3();
    private Camera camera;
    private boolean unproject = true;

    public LetterActor(Texture letterTexture, Camera theCamera)
    {
        texture = letterTexture;
        camera = theCamera;

        touchPosition.set(0, 0, 0);
        camera.unproject(touchPosition);

        setSize(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());

        addListener(new InputListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
                touchPosition.set(x, y, 0);
                if (unproject)
                {
                    camera.unproject(touchPosition);
                }
                setPosition(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
                touchPosition.set(x, y, 0);
                if (unproject)
                {
                    camera.unproject(touchPosition);
                }
                setPosition(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);
            }

            @Override
            public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)
            {
                touchPosition.set(x, y, 0);
                if (unproject)
                {
                    camera.unproject(touchPosition);
                }
                setPosition(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
        batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta){
        //setBounds(getX(), getY(),getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}



package com.xxxx.yyyy;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class LetterLoader {

    public static Texture[] loadLetters()
    {
        Texture[] letters = new Texture[26];

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            char letter = (char) (i + 65);
            letters[i] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bigletters/" + letter + ".png"));
        }

        return letters;
    }
}





package com.xxxx.yyyy;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ExtendViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Touchable;

public class WordPuzzle extends ApplicationAdapter
{
    private final static float SCALE = 4f;
    private final static float INV_SCALE = 1.f / SCALE;

    private final static float VP_WIDTH = 1280 * INV_SCALE;
    private final static float VP_HEIGHT = 720 * INV_SCALE;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private ExtendViewport viewport;
    private Stage stage;

    private LetterActor letterActor;

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new ExtendViewport(VP_WIDTH, VP_HEIGHT, camera);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setViewport(viewport);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        Texture[] textures = LetterLoader.loadLetters();
        for (int i = 0; i < textures.length; i++)
        {
            letterActor = new LetterActor(textures[i], camera);
            letterActor.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
            stage.addActor(letterActor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }


    @Override public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        viewport.update(width, height, true);
    }

    @Override public void dispose()
    {
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original question, the flip-flopping of the drawn position might have been from you calling `setBounds` over and over. I'm not sure.

To answer your new questions: If you were not using Scene2D, you would need to convert screen coordinates to world coordinates by unprojecting. This is done by the camera. The camera holds the data that defines how the world coordinate system is projected to the screen coordinate system, so it can do the calculations to project and unproject back and forth. But you are wrong that you would need to project back to screen coordinates after reacting to the new coordinates. That is handled in the shader when it projects the scene to the screen, and you don't need to worry about that unless using custom shaders. You only ever have to work with world coordinates, and only need to unproject when you are handed screen coordinates.

However, what I missed before is that you're using Stage and its associated InputListener. Stage unprojects the screen coordinates before it gives them to InputListener, so you don't need to worry about unprojecting or projecting at all!

---

Relevant info from my original answer:

Remove your `actorX` and `actorY` from the class because they are redundant. Use `getX()`, `getY()`, `setX()`, `setY()`, `setPosition()`, etc. instead.

You also don't need to be calling `setBounds` over and over. Just call `setSize()` one time when the class is instantiated. The bounds will then be automatically updated whenever you call `setPosition()`. *(I noticed that you were setting bounds with double the size of the texture. Maybe you were compensating for it not being unprojected correctly?)*

For your `draw` method, you should use `getX()` and `getY()`, and I would assume you also want to draw it to the same size as its bounds, so also use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
    batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

Comment: I updated the original post, this comment was made to the old version.

Comment: I must have been distracted when I wrote this answer. Since you're using Stage, the unprojecting is already done for you before x and y are sent to the InputListener, so you don't need to worry about that. Sorry, I'll update.

Comment: @user3591115 Is it still drawing in two places if you remove the unproject step?

Comment: I will post a new thread as well as I changed the code a lot. I have gotten rid of the double drawings but my positons are still off.